# button from other xml file, want to setText()

Tags: android, xml, triggers

I have 2 XMLs in my Android App.
And want to do this : `examplebuttononthesecondXML.setText("12");`
with a button on the second XML.

**At first how my App should work:**

- There is a Textfield where you can put in a Text
- By pressing the Button Save, it will open a Dialogue Box with 10
  Buttons.
- Each Button has a Number.
- With the Buttons you should put in your Password.
- Then you can press Ok. And everything is saved.

**Everytime the Dialogue Box opens the Buttons Numbers should appear in another order!**
(for more security).

the only Problem is how to get Access to my second XML File.

```
// b1 = button on the second XML;
// buttons = Name of the secnond XML;
// testb  = Name of the Button Variable which has access to b1;


setContentView(R.layout.buttons);


Button testb = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.b1);

testb.setText("showme");
```

The above doesn't work, instead, it crashes down my app!!

**setcontentview is the reason!**

maybe you have an idea :D

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could you `LayoutInflator` to access that `xml` file just follow this example code

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
     = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
      .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

then

```
LinearLayout myOtherLayoutMainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tool_box, null);
```

or simply use View to access that `XML` file

```
View myOtherLayoutMainLinearLayout = (View)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tool_box, null);
```

and to access the button simply

```
 Button myOtherXMLButton = (Button)myOtherLayoutMainLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.tool_box);
myOtherXMLButton.setText("xxxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View myOtherLayoutMainLinearLayout = (View)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bbb, null);
       Button myOtherXMLButton = (Button)myOtherLayoutMainLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button1);
       myOtherXMLButton.setText("xxxx");
       setupButton();
```

ok this causes no failure anymore :D
but after i opened my dialogue the number on my button1 is the same...